# Which firebase database to use for chat applicatoin, Firestore or Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, chat

I'm building an app which uses Firestore for storing most data. The app has a chat functionality and I was considering using Realtime Database for that. What are the benefits of using Firebase Firestore vs Realtime Database for this chat functionality? If there is no difference, should I use Firestore for everything?

P.S. I have already read the firebase comparison of the two https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore and I am still not sure which way to go about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FB RTDB was designed for a chat application but is not so great for more than simple querying. Firestore was developed to improve the querying requirements and is newer. Newer doesn't necessarily mean better, depends on the use case. Their pricing models are very different, so you need to understand how your use case will be charged.

You can use both of course. They can work well together but if a simple chat requirement is all you need, I would use RTDB.

PS. The unique keys generated in RTDB for each new record are automatically in chronological order, which relates back to it being designed for a chat app. There is a caveat though, the chat messages may still get out of order because the keys are generated on the device and if the device clocks are slightly out and messages are being exchanged rapidly then you may get a miss timing. The way round this is to write each record with a property of server time...and use that to sort the chat messages. Hope that helps your decision.

PPS. RTDB charges for data storage volumes and data download volumes. Firestore charges for storage and db reads and writes. There will be a lot of the latter in a chat app so I would recommend running some what-if scenarios in Excel.

Comment: I've found that Firebase also answered this in one of their "Get to know firestore" videos online. Here is the link for it https://youtu.be/6NegFl9p_sE?t=395